# Problem with repeated icons

Tags: interaction-design, icons, design-patterns

What's the best way to avoid repeating icons on each row, it clutters the layout and takes attention from other important elements.

[image: Repeated icons]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they're really the same in each column, just take them out and place them as column titles. This way you can also attach a label to them and not leave the users guessing.

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution, problem is I can't use any more vertical space. So I wouldn't be able to fit this, most probably users already see those icons in other parts of the app and already know what they are.

Comment: Is there are a lot if rows, users may forget which is which.

Comment: It's just a simple table, like thousands of other tables on the web and elsewhere. Solutions exist for very long tables as well, e.g. repeating or sticky title row.

Answer (score 8):

Or, perhaps something like this?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRx5qG.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This way, you don't really have two columns of the same icons, but you still see them. You could even color them on hover behind the counter label, if you have a mouse-based UI.

Answer (score 5):

You may only show them on hover. Or you may use greyed out icons and color them on hover. This way, they do not get too much attention.

Comment: This is the best solution and widely implemented. I'd suggest displaying the icons on the first row of objects, and keep the rest on hover. This way the user is given a clue about the UI and encouraged to see how the icons for lower rows would appear.